# Проверка первого символа строки

Tags: java

Мне нужно вывести первый символ и проверить, чем он является. Где-то подсмотрел, что можно использовать `str.length()`

Вот, например, кусочек кода:

```
String str = "Первый символ строки";
int first = str.length()-1;// на форуме где читал, там был пример с последним символом, поэтому -1, а 0 не работает
char ch = str.charAt(first);
System.out.println(ch);
```

Собственно проблему описал в комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить первый символ строки можно с помощью

```
char c = str.charAt(0);
```

Но вы это и так знаете. Что значит проверить на истину? Зачем вам длина строки?

Comment: например, такая задача: Если Вы мужчина, то выведите сообщение. Если Вы женщина, то выведите сообщение

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: Вот такое короткое условие: если вы мужчина, то... если вы женщина, то... Видимо, нужно создать строку, например, male, вернуть первый символ и им проверять, мужчина или женщина)

Comment: Типа человек вводит `male` или `female`? Тогда надо сделать оператор `if`. `if(c == 'm') { } else if(c == 'f') { }`, а лучше сравнить всю строку с помощью методa `str.equals("male")`, или, если male - это только начало строки, то `str.startsWith("male")`.